# Which system call will "top" call in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

1.only fork 2. only exec 3. both fork & exec

This may be a simple question, but I'm really confused with it. I'm really a newbie and don't know how to figure it out.

I'll be very glad if someone can explain it to me.

Thank u very much.

Comment: Why not use `strace` to find out?

Comment: @KerrekSB only exec found. So it means only exec is called?

Comment: @Lynn yep `exec` is called and `fork` is not. But that's NOT THE ONLY one system call called during a `top`.

Comment: The more important/interesting functions `top` would use in my opinon would be `sysconf` to read various system settings as well as `open` and `read` to read data from `proc`. Why would `top` need to fork anyway? Or maybe I'm confusing the meaning of "top"... we're talking of the thing that shows CPU usage and processes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed, many.

use `strace top` to see.

---

**ADDITION:**

In fact, there is no `fork` but an `exec`:

```
[pengyu@pengyu-Studio-1747 temp]$strace top 2> a.txt
[pengyu@pengyu-Studio-1747 temp]$cat a.txt | grep fork
[pengyu@pengyu-Studio-1747 temp]$cat a.txt | grep exec
execve("/usr/bin/top", ["top"], [/* 60 vars */]) = 0
```